# Multiple slash in URL replacement though regex

Tags: regex, url, pcre, regexp-replace, akamai

I am trying to create a regex in pcre, that is going to salinize URL with multiple slashes like the following:

`https://www.domin.com/test1/////test2/somemoretests_67142 https://www.domin.com/test1/test2/somemoretests_67142///// https://www.domin.com/test1/test2///somemoretests_67142`

So that I can replace it with the following: `https://\2\4` and the link at the end of it looks: `https://www.domin.com/test1/test2/somemoretests_67142`

I have been struggling with it for the past couple of days, so any regex guru help is more than welcome :)

I have tried the following and more:

`(http|https):\/\/(.*)(\/\/+)(.*)`
`(http|https):\/\/(.*)(\/\/){2,}(.*)`
`(http|https):\/\/(.*)(\/\/{2})(.*)`

I am going to utilize these for Akamai to sanitize our URLs though cloudlet.

Comment: You could search for something like `(?<!:)[\/]+(?=\/)|\/$` and substitute that with the empty string. The idea is to either capture groups of slashes that are not preceeded by a colon but followed by yet another slash or a single slash at the end of the line. That way we leave a slash where we need it as seperator yet remove it at the end where it does nothing for us.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
(?<!https:\/)(?<!http:\/)(\/+$|(?<=\/)\/+)
```

And substitute the first group with empty string.

[Regex demo.](https://regex101.com/r/K6cMTk/1)

---

This will produce this output:

```
https://www.domin.com/test1/test2/somemoretests_67142
https://www.domin.com/test1/test2/somemoretests_67142
https://www.domin.com/test1/test2/somemoretests_67142
```